# How to display the message sent on the contact form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a contact form and it does work but now I want to display "Message Sent" after submitting the form right below the "Send" button.

**HTML file**

```
<form action="send_mail.php" id="footer-form" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="sr-only" for="name2">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Enter email" required="" type="email" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="sr-only" for="message2">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message2" name="message2" placeholder="Message" required="" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="6u 12u$(small)">
        <input id="copy" name="copy" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="copy">Email me a copy of this message</label>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code** (different file)

```
<?php 

$name        = $_POST['name2'];
$email       = $_POST['email2'];
$message     = $_POST['message2'];
$formcontent ="From: $name \nMessage: $message";
$recipient   = "hello@domain.com";
$subject     = "Contact Form";
$mailheader  = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

Comment: Is this what you're file looks like or is the form and your code in different files?

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, the form and the code are on different files. I just took the form codes only

Comment: You need to clarify all that in your question or you will get answers that doesn't suit your situation. If I were you, I would look into Ajax. Much smoother user experience since you don't need to reload the page when posting the form.

Comment: Thank, I will look into that. Thank you

Comment: I haven’t tried it. I’m not feeling good. But I will try tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply redirect your php to your html with a parameter like success=true after your *mail()* function

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: index.php?success=true');
```

rename your .html to .php

and in your html (now php) under the

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send" />
<?php
  if ( isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success']==true ) 
    echo "Message Sent";
?>
```

Comment: I think this is the best one. I will try it and update you if it works

Comment: This works but it now overriding the HTML5 validation. When I click the send button with empty fields the "Message Sent" is displayed.

Comment: No it's because you already send a message, try without any parameters in the url ;)

Comment: There is nothing on the URL and I still get the message sent with all textboxes cleared

Comment: maybe try if ( isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success']==true) ) instead of if ($_GET['success']==true)

Comment: I tried with url : index.php and  :

 <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send" />
<?php
  if ( isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success']==true) 
    echo "Message Sent";
?>
it works perfectly.

Comment: It does sent the contact form and the information is sent to the specified email address but the issue is that the validation doesn't work anymore. The textboxes are all empty but still the message is displayed

Comment: it's really weird can you create a plunkr with your code so I can test it ?

Comment: Hey Nico, I gotta say, thank you a lot. It's now working. I figured out that I was using the old html codes without 'required="'.

Comment: Ahah, that's happen! Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, Now i'm trying to include the checkbox where if it's checked the contact form will also be sent to the senders email provided on the email textbox

Answer (score 0):

Just as Funk Forty Niner said:

Use a if/else statement:

```
<?php 

$name        = $_POST['name2'];
$email       = $_POST['email2'];
$message     = $_POST['message2'];
$formcontent ="From: $name \nMessage: $message";
$recipient   = "hello@domain.com";
$subject     = "Contact Form";
$mailheader  = "From: $email \r\n";
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    die("Error!");
} else {
    echo "Success!";
}
?>
```

`if/else` Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score -1):

Real simple, use a conditional statement with an `if/else`.

```
if( mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) ){
    echo "Sent";
} else { 
    echo "Error, check your logs"; 
}
```

Plus, if your entire code is in the same file, you best be using a conditional statement for all inputs/POST arrays and checking for `empty()` fields.

Comment: Hi @Funk, thanks for the suggestion, it does work but I want it to be displayed below the "Send" button with some good formatting. The one you suggested goes to another page which is the "send_email.php"

Comment: @lemonadejuice501 this will depend on where your html is placed in conjunction with your php. You can and if you're not already doing this, would be to have your entire code in one file and using conditional statements as I outlined in the answer. Usually the php will be after the HTML and just below and outside the form.